# Request attributes return null in construct

Tags: php, laravel, request

I define $request->attributes in middleware

```
$request->attributes->add(['user' => $user ]);
```

when i use

```
$request->attributes('user')
```

in function it work and return value
but when use in __construct return null !
i need to use

> $request->attributes

in __construct in laravel 5.8

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\v1;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    protected $user;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->userModel          = new User;
        $this->user               = request()->attributes->get('user');//It return null
    }

public function showWallet(Request $request)
    {
       #$this->user               = request()->attributes->get('user');//It return value
        $credit = $this->walletModel->getCredit($this->user);
        //Some codes
    }
```

Comment: The controller is not necessarily associated with a request. The request is not set when the controller is constructed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor is called before any middleware is run so you'll need to wrap you code is a closure and pass it to the controllers `middleware` method:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->userModel = new User;

    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {

        $this->user = $request->attributes->get('user');

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

The above will allow you to access the `attributes` property because it will run after your route middleware (where you defined the `attributes`), and before the controller method for the route so you can set the `user` property.